# processing/parsing command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have written the next simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc<2) {
       return 0;
   }
   else {
       double x = atof(argv[1]);
       printf ("%f\n", x);
       return 0;
   }
}
```

For example

```
./test 3.14
```

outputs

```
3.140000
```

Now I am trying to use this program with some other program, which gives outputs of the following form:

```
[3.14
```

Or just some other symbol in front of 3.14, but not a number. I want to use this output as input for the simple program I just showed, obviously I can't just pass this as an argument. My question is therefore how to accomplish this. I thought a lot about this problem, and tried to search the internet, but this is such a specific problem, I couldn't find answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always exactly one non-numeric character at the beginning of the output string for this program?

Comment: You **can** pass it as an argument.  Assuming you're using Bash (or similar): `./test $(./other_program | sed 's/[//')`.

Comment: `double x=atof(argv[1]+1);` but then again you could circumvent the entire convert-to-double routine and just `printf("%s", argv[1]+1);`

Comment: +1@jongware. In addition lets mention that for production quality code, a lot of error handling is of course missing arond the atof.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks, do you alsno know how to handle it if I had 3.14] instead of [3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
char *str = argv[1] + 1
float pi = atof(str);
printf("%f\n", pi);
```

Or, if you don't know how many non-digits will lead the number:

```
char *str = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
    if(isdigit(*(argv[1] + i)))
    {
        str = argv[1] + i;
        break;
    }
}

if(str)
{
    float pi = atof(str);
    printf("%f\n", pi);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sscanf` instead of `atof` to do a simple parse of a not-too-complicated string:

```
 double x;

 if (sscanf (argv[1], "[%lf", &x) == 1) {
     printf ("found a [ followed by %f\n", x);
 }
 else {
     printf ("hmm, '%s' didn't look like a [ followed by a double value\n", argv[1]);
 }
```

Please refer to your friendly `scanf` (or `sscanf`) manual page for details of the possibilities to parse various items.

Comment: How about instead of saying `"hmm ..."`, say `"Error! Error! Nukes are launching..."`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Because I hesitate to make assumptions about the OP's installed hardware :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2)
        return 1;
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(argv[1])+1);
    char *d, *s;
    for(d=temp, s=argv[1]; *s ; ++s){
        if(isdigit(*s) || *s == '.' || *s == '-'){//cleaning
            *d++ = *s;
        }
    }
    *d = '\0';
    char *endp;
    double x = strtod(temp, &endp);
    if(*endp == '\0')
        printf("%f\n", x);
    free(temp);

    return 0;
}
```